# Central sources of NinePatch Images?

Tags: android, user-interface, resources, nine-patch

Are there any central spots or collection in the net from created NinePatches?

I think they are real fancy and useful things. Even if you are not a designer this can bring you great benefit and look. But I think it would be great if there would be some collections for this in the internet as they are available for icons. But I didn't found anything useful. 
So I ask you if know such spots or webpages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of blogs out there with a few images:

- http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/custom-color-buttons-for-android/

and one posting a batch converter:

- http://stella.laurenzo.org/2011/05/batch-9-patch-image-editing/

But they are quite easy to create yourself. Use the dev guide, those blogs and my answer here: [How to create android spinner without down triangle on the right side of the widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058360/how-to-create-android-spinner-without-down-triangle-on-the-right-side-of-the-widg/5928041#5928041) to learn about them.

Then, just use draw9patch or Gimp (both free) to make them.

Comment: Note that first link is broken

Answer (score 7):

I am trying to build a huge central for 9-patch images.

Feel free to visit and grab whatever you need from there.

As long as it is for building your android applications :)

http://android9patch.blogspot.com/

Comment: Make sure you review the nine patches I have provided on the website. Some of them could probably be tweaked to perform better. The site is pretty old.