# Is there any place I can download 9 patch PNGs?

Tags: android, png

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Central sources of NinePatche Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005742/central-sources-of-ninepatche-images)

I'm looking for some sort of downloadable 9-patch images to use in my Android app.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Is there any resource for this?