# Do I need to use Draw9Patch for image buttons?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and I was wondering if I need to render a png with draw9patch for a image button? Is that necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this [Simple Nine-patch Generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)

This [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005742/central-sources-of-ninepatche-images) also addresses yours