# How to align an ImageButton in Android FrameLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-imagebutton, android-framelayout

My app's layout is FrameLayout.  I want to align an ImageButton to right top of the framelayout.  I tried below code not worked.

```
    mImageButton = new ImageButton(mContext);
    LayoutParams ll = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
    ll.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    mImageButton.setLayoutParams(ll);
    mImageButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light));
    this.addView(mImageButton);
```

[image: expected output]expected output

Comment: check this resource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060688/how-can-i-align-an-element-to-the-right-in-the-framelayout  it says try to use relativelayout. is framelayout a hard requirement for you?

Comment: @Manoj Rey Pham's solution is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the construction code of LayoutParams to:

```
LayoutParams ll = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
```

In your code, you set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` value to `MATCH_PARENT` , so your ImageView will fill all your parent FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide height width in layout params. Because with match_parent it will take width and height of parent or you can use WRAP_CONTENT.

```
 mImageButton = new ImageButton(mContext);
LayoutParams ll = new LayoutParams(width,height);
ll.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
mImageButton.setLayoutParams(ll);
mImageButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light));
this.addView(mImageButton);
```

Comment: I forgot to add Gravity.TOP. Main problem was that you were using MATCH_PARENT. Check now this should also work . You can give specific width and height to your image button as well that's why I mentiond width height. I have also metioned that you can use wrap content

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;

mImageButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: check answer if this is better solution @Krishna