# Android how to position toggle button light

Tags: android

`

Hi,

I have requirement of using my own background and blue light for toggle button.

However, using this i am not able to custom position light of toggle button which is always placed to the bottom of button.

I want to move it above and just below center of button.

I tried with paddingBottom but that did not help. Any help regarding this appreciated.

-Thanks,
Manju

Comment: to the button of button?

Answer (score 1):

That light is part of the nine-patch png. If you create new backgrounds, you need to add your own "on" and "off" circles to the file. You then use the border lines of the nine-patch to prevent stretching of the circle.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Read also my answer here for another explanation: [How to create android spinner without down triangle on the right side of the widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058360/how-to-create-android-spinner-without-down-triangle-on-the-right-side-of-the-widg/5928041#5928041)

Comment: Hi Aleadam, thanks for your response. I have added my own nine-patch file for light on/off, but this light is placed at the bottom of toggle button and it is hardly 8 pixels above from the bottom of button. I want to move this light above with at least 20 pixels. I tried using android:paddingBottom for ToggleButton but that did not move the light even by 1pixel up. Is there any option to move this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a LayerList and position the graphic on the toggle button by enclosing the drawable in a bitmap tag, and set its gravity to 'center' - see [LayerList here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) great thing is that this works with selectors as drawables too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a relativeLayout and do android:layout_Below, if I understand your question correctly