# EditText problem

Tags: android

I've got an EditText...

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/box" android:autoText="true"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dip"
 android:singleLine="true" android:hint="Enter" />
```

Is it possible to make the text only appear up on till say... 50dip from the end of the EditText?

So when typing a query it'd look like

```
 ____________________
 |y query is cool   |
 --------------------
```

while typing `my query is cool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `paddingRight` in this case (assuming I understood you correctly). Here is an example:

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/box"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"                                     
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Enter" 
        android:text="1234567890ABCDEF-1234567890ABCDEF"/>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best alternative is to create your own nine-patch file and decide exactly how much padding you want.

See my answer here for a quick intro: [How to create android spinner without down triangle on the right side of the widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058360/how-to-create-android-spinner-without-down-triangle-on-the-right-side-of-the-widg/5928041#5928041)

and the official docs here:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch
- http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Then, you should use

```
android:gravity="right"
```

inside your EditText

Answer (score 0):

im a little confused also as to what you were going for, my first thought would be to add

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/box"
android:autoText="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="45dip"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="start"
android:hint="Enter" />
```

but maybe that wasn't what you meant? you could use this in combination with the techniques listed about so that the user wouldn't be confused by the missing characters.