# How can I style the title of the Spinner dialog by xml?

Tags: android, xml, styles, spinner

In my current implementation, I have modified the whole style of my application...

I successfully modified the Spinner style, so I was able to change the RadioButton look and feel:

[image]

I am now working on the title, but seems really hard to style.
I would like to change, for instance the title text color (and optionally removing the triangle)

I know I could do that by extending Spinner or Dialog, but I have to do achieve that by playing with xml.

Here is my current code that succesfully modified other dialog properties:

```
<style name="Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerDark</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemDark</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/DropDownItemDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I like style of your spinner. Could you please share how could we do that.
I am trying to achieve same but no success.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To change the triangle, you could use the second answer here:  [How to create android spinner without down triangle on the right side of the widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058360/how-to-create-android-spinner-without-down-triangle-on-the-right-side-of-the-wid)

I haven't yet figured out how to style the main text, but you may just be able to apply normal text field formatting to it via the Spinner in xml (textColor, etc).

Comment: The link you gave me is for the triagle in the widget itself, not in the popup that appear with the item list.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  :(  I can't actually seem to find a way to do it via XML.  You may be stuck with doing it in code, at best (but I can't seem to find a way to do it in code without extending as you mentioned above).