# Trying to get my custom spinner look to work

Tags: android, spinner

I have edited the spinner image by changing the color of it.  Then used the draw9patch.bat tool to create it into a proper 9-patch file, and then renamed it to spinner_updated.9.png, then I placed it into my "res/drawable" folder.  So I then checked out this link just to get an idea of implementing a custom spinner:

[How to create android spinner without down triangle on the right side of the widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058360/how-to-create-android-spinner-without-down-triangle-on-the-right-side-of-the-wid)

I tried using lencinhaus & Aleadam ways but when I try to actually use it in my app I keep getting the error:

```
Failed to convert @android:drawable/spinner_updated into a drawable
Couldn't resolve resource @android:drawable/spinner_updated
```

What am I doing wrong?  What would I do once I have the image I want to use for my spinner to actually get it displaying in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using your own drawable you need to use:

```
@drawable/spinner_updated
```

The `@android:` directs the app to look in Android's built-in resources not your own.