# Change Spinner Arrow

Tags: java, android, layout

I need to change the arrow of a Spinner view to look like the next image.

[image: asd]

I've tried with a new xml file and i only can modify the background (But I get a gray padding too).

I need to know if it's possible to make this without changing the png files from the core.

Comment: Also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058360/how-to-create-android-spinner-without-down-triangle-on-the-right-side-of-the-wid