# How I can change the title of the spinner

Tags: android, spinner, title

How I can change the title (color, background, textSize...) of the spinner. I have looked some post, but do not have the same code that my app.

main.class

```
public class cargarSpinner() {

      listaSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerInfo>();  
  listaSpinner = cargarListSpinner();

      SpinnerAdapter myAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter
            (this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                    listaSpinner);

      spinner.setPrompt("Title");
      spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

spinner_row.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fondoSpinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/spinner_naranja_gradiente"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textSpinner"
    style="@style/SpinnerText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

in XMl use this :

```
android:prompt="@string/spinner_title
```

in java code:

```
spinner.setPrompt("Title")
```

Comment: Go through this link..it may be help u..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom spinner layout with custom spinner adapter as follow

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.travelreasons, R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

your **layout.simple_spinner_item**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Your **layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item**

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

For styles add your custom dimensions and height as per your requirement.

```
<style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">

  </style>

  <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">

  </style>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android)

Comment: I have a custom spinner.

Comment: i have custom items. i only want custom title.

Comment: Using custom style you can create your own type of style for spinner I have used default in parent you can set your style as parent

Comment: i want put my code of spinneradapter but i can´t because the web lunch a error. you can put only the code for custom title adapted to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Title");
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0,
            wordtoSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0,
            wordtoSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

spinner.setPrompt(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: and the background color?

Answer (score -1):

Using Java (Code):

spinner.setPrompt("Title")

OR

From XML:

android:prompt="@string/spinner_title

for styling it

please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058360/how-to-create-android-spinner-without-down-triangle-on-the-right-side-of-the-wid)

Comment: this property is deprecated now