# Android - Remove Spinner Dropdown Arrow

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner, android-selector

I'm just wondering if it's at all possible to simply remove the dropdown arrow for a spinner? I have a drawable arrow in a backgroud layout for my spinner, however the system default arrow appears to the right of the spinner, which I would like to get rid of.

Here is the spinner xml code for my activity layout

```
<Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSelectStaff"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/empty"/>
```

And my custom spinner layout looks like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:background="@drawable/spinner_text_shape"
          android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
          android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check this link may it help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058360/how-to-create-android-spinner-without-down-triangle-on-the-right-side-of-the-wid

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, I've been searching on how to do this for a couple of hours now before asking.

Comment: Just saw your comment @ZubairAkber, thanks heaps! Not sure how I missed that,  I'm usually a pro at Googling. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This may help You

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner" name="SpinnerwithNoArrow">
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And then:

```
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerSelectStaff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/empty"/>
```

Use this style in ur spinner

Comment: this looks strange if you use material design...the answer below is correct

Comment: Setting `android:theme="@style/SpinnerwithNoArrow"` causes my spinner to crash when it's clicked.

Answer (score 159):

If you don't want to declare a specific style, use `background @null` in the layout XML file.

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null" />
```

Comment: is there any way to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: @MihirPatel, Spinner is View, so you can try `spinner.setBackground(null)`

Comment: Is there any way to return the default spinner arrow back after setting background null ?

Comment: @AndriyAntoniv, you can programmatically save it as a variable, before setting the background to null and you'll have the original one to use it whenever you like.

Comment: @Galya Actually I was trying to avoid storing the default value in my own variable. IMO it would be much better to have some method provided by android which can reset Spinner background state to default

Answer (score 20):

Please try this simple way:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 5):

Both answers were not helpful for me, so here is a really simple one-line solution that worked.

```
  //some spinner initialisation stuff->
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

  //some spinner initialisation stuff->
mySpinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

I can't tell for sure if it will work with just a default spinner layout, but it worked well with my custom that I created for other needs.